# How to prove the complexity of a logarithmic function?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Let's say you were given two logarithmic functions like
[image]

and you were asked to find if f(n) is O(g(n)) Ω(g(n)) or Θ(g(n)), how would you go about it? I found questions like these easier when you were comparing two exponential equations, because for example with x(n) = n^2 and p(n) = n^2 you could find a c > 0 (ex 3) where x(n) <= cp(n) for all n greater than some n>0 and that would prove that x(n) = O(p(n)). However, comparing two logarithmic functions seems much more difficult for some reason. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The procedure does not change. What's the problem looking for these constants? And your *exponential functions* are not exponential functions. They are polynomials.

Comment: Hint: log n**2 = 2 log n. 2 log n is clearly big-Theta(log n).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Is the question how to *rigorously prove* things like this, or how to *intuitively determine* things like this?

Answer (score 0):

`f(n)` is `O(g(n))` iff there is `a` constant `c` and `n_0` such that `f(n) <= c * g(n)` for each `n >= n_0`.
f(n) is `Ω(g(n))` iff there is a constant `c` and `n_0` such that `f(n) >= c * g(n)` for each `n >= n_0`.

Now, `f(n)` is `Θ(g(n))` iff `f(n)` is `O(g(n))` and `f(n)` is `Ω(g(n))`.

So, in your cases, we have:

```
f(n) = log (n^2) = 2logn
```

which means, `g(n)` is `logn` and `c = 2`, which means `f(n) <= 2 * logn` and `f(n) >= 2 * logn`, which makes it `Ω(logn)`.

Btw. its also `f(n) <= n` and `f(n) >= 1`, so `f(n)` can be `O(n)`, but we don't use it, since we can find a better `O(g(n))`. In this case we don't have the same function in both notations, to for those values we don't have `Ω`. However, we just need one option for `g(n)` to declare `Ω`. In cases we can't find it, we say its not `Ω`. Note the word "we say".

In second case, we care only for "highest growing value", `logn` part. Now, `c = 1`, and `g = log(n)`, so in this case, its also `Ω(logn)`.